# Как удалить lineSymbol с карты

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Не могу удалить символ с **polylines**

```
/* 
| Построение трека по заданным параметрам
| Функция построения трека 
*/
function build_road_map(options) {

    clearMap();

    /* Переменная точки движения по polyline */
    lineSymbol = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        hidden: true,
        scale: 5,
        strokeColor: '#393'
    };


    /* Область показа маркеров (Для центровки карты по области) */
    var markersBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    /* Конвертируем JSON в объект */
    options = JSON.parse(options);     

    remove_polylines();
    /* Определяем линии google polyline для построения линий */
    polylines = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: options.coordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        icons: [{
            icon: lineSymbol,
            offset: '100%'
        }]
    });

    /* Удаляем все линии */
    polylines.setMap(null); 
    /* Устанавливаем новые линии */
    polylines.setMap(map);

    /* Удаляем все маркеры */
    remove_marker();

    /* Устанавливаем маркеры (Начальный и конечный) */
    if (options.markers.is) {
        add_marker(markersBounds, options.markers.start, 'A');
        add_marker(markersBounds, options.markers.end, 'B');
    } 

    /* Центрируем и масштабируем карту */
    map.setCenter(markersBounds.getCenter(), map.fitBounds(markersBounds));

    /* Анимация движения */
    if (options.motion_animation) {
        animateCircle(polylines);
    }
}


/*
| Анимация движения
| Функция для изменения смещения символа с фиксированными интервалами
*/
function animateCircle(line) {

    var icons = line.get('icons');                
    var count = 0;

    var listener = window.setInterval(function() {
        count = (count + 1) % 200;                    
        icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
        line.set('icons', icons);
    }, 50);

}

/* 
| Управление маркерами
| Функция удаления всех маркеров
*/
function remove_marker() {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }

    markers = [];
}

/*
| Управление линиями
| Функция удаления всех линий
*/
function remove_polylines() {

    for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
        polylines[i].setMap(null);
    }

    polylines = [];

}

/* 
| Управление маркерами
| Функция добавление маркера на карту
*/
function add_marker(markersBounds, location, label) { 

    /* Определяем широту и долготу в формате google */
    LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);

    /* Определяем маркер */
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLng,
        label: label,
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: location.title
    });

    /* Устанавливаем маркер */
    marker.setMap(map);
    markers.push(marker);

    /* Определяем контент */
    var content = location.content;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

    /* Устанавливаем обработчик при нажатии на маркер */
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow) { 
        return function() {
           infowindow.setContent(content);
           infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
    })(marker, content, infowindow)); 

    /* Выводим контент для маркера */
    if (location.show_content) {
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: content });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }

    /* Добавляем координаты маркера в область */
    markersBounds.extend(LatLng);

}

/*
| Сброс всей карты на чистое состояние и сброс всех переменных
| используется для отображения каждого запроса
*/
function clearMap() {

    /* Очистить все линии */
    for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
        polylines[i].setMap(null);
    }

    /* Очистить все маркеры */
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }

    /* Очистить все */
    polylines = [];
    markers = [];

}
```

При повторном вызове функции **animateCircle(polylines)** накладывается второй символ, при последующем вызове добавляется ещё один символ и так N раз.

Карту очищаю, маркеры очищаю, линии тоже. Но символ не удаляется.

Принцип работы карты такой: Инициализация карты, а потом все функции по карте без перезагрузок

Подскажите как удалить символ?